# Unable to connect local Firebase emulator suite Hosting with Firestore (Web version 9)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to test my app with the firebase local emulator suite, which uses hosting, firestore and cloud functions.

I setup my app for the local emulator with the following code, referring to the instructions in https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#web-version-9.

```
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);
```

Then I was able to start up my local emulator with no errors using the following command

`firebase emulators:start --project demo-<PROJECT_ID>`

substituting <PROJECT_ID> and <LOCAL_DIR> with my actual project id and local directory.

Terminal output:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, storage
i  emulators: Detected demo project ID <PROJECT_ID>, emulated services will use a demo configuration and attempts to access non-emulated services for this project will fail.
+  functions: Using node@14 from host.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: build
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "<LOCAL_DIR>" for Cloud Functions...
+  functions[us-central1-makeUppercase]: firestore function initialized.
+  functions[us-central1-onCreateEntry]: firestore function initialized.

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ localhost:9099 │ http://localhost:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions      │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting        │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ localhost:9199 │ http://localhost:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

But when I try to create a new Firestore document through my app hosted in local emulator, nothing is shown in my Firestore local emulator. Nor did I get any errors on my browser's console.

I was able to create new documents manually and communicate with my Cloud Functions local emulator in the Firestore local emulator. No problem. Only facing problems when I try to communicate with Firestore through my app.

What did I miss ? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, here is my firebase.js I am using in my react app.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  getFirestore,
  connectFirestoreEmulator,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();

if (process.env.REACT_APP_TARGET.toUpperCase() === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
  connectAuthEmulator(
    auth,
    process.env.REACT_APP_EMULATOR_HOST + '/',
  );
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', '8080');
}

export { auth, db, firebaseConfig };
export default app;
```